# message.guild.id comparing crashing my bot discord.js v12?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have my command handler which was working well all the time, but now it randomly crashed my bot when comparing guild ID. The error was `Cannot read property 'id' of null`. My code is this (the important bit):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '&';

const version = '1.1';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(command === 'acqs'){
        if ( message.guild.id === '541003397462097921') {
            client.commands.get('heavenacqs').execute(message, args);
        } else message.reply(`this command isn't supported in this server yet.`);
    }
```

What have I done wrong and/or how to fix it? Thanks :)

Comment: How does your command handler looks like? It seems like `message` is not passed or null.

Comment: Is the command ran in a server or a DM?

Comment: I've updated my code, so there is basically the whole main file, I have more commands, but I've left just that one which has the problem. @Variable

Comment: The command is run in a server @Jakye

Comment: @MichalKachlík Try wrapping your onMessage event inside `client.on("ready", () => {});`. As a matter of fact, always wrap all other events inside the `onReady` event.

Comment: @Variable Absolutely do not do this. The message event will not be fired until the client is ready anyway, all this does is open up the code to potentially having multiple duplicate message events (`ready` may fire multiple times in normal operation when the shard is asked to reconnect).

Comment: @Klaycon I always do that, and I never had problems with it. It's safer for me to wait for the bot to be ready and then capture anything. You can also do `.once` to ensure this event is only fired once.

Comment: @Variable Just checked the source. Events are queued until the client turns ready, and the client only emits ready once. While your method will technically work it is unnecessary and probably ultimately bad practice. I would recommend against it.

Comment: @Klaycon any other reason why I shouldn't do it that way besides that all other events are queued? Because i'm curious now as it can't do any harm in my eyes. I'm also loading up different tasks like booting up a database connection once onReady is fired. And why does onReady event returns a callback, why not only `client.on("ready")`?

Comment: @Variable If you need to do any asynchronous operation (such as file accesses) in order to create the event listeners, there will be a small period between turning ready and the command handler being assigned where you can receive messages but have no handler for them yet. There's no reason for this to be the case, you could have been doing those operations while the bot was readying up. And you still could do it that way (storing the commands etc. outside of the ready event) but then you still have everything nested a whole indent level further for no reason.

Comment: @Variable The only thing the ready event is useful for is logging when the bot turns ready and editing the bot's status (which can only be done once fully connected to the gateway). Aside from that the event isn't super useful.

Comment: @Variable one more thing I thought of - it's also the place where you're guaranteed to have most things cached, so if you need to perform operations on particular channels, servers, users, etc by ID you should get them in the ready event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bot is most likely receiving messages in DMs, in which case discord.js will provide `null` as the `message.guild`. Even if your bot somehow didn't have the guild cached it would provide a partial guild or throw an error instead of providing `null`.

Add a check that the message was sent in a guild before trying to use it.

```
if(message.guild && message.guild.id === '541003397462097921')
```

If you never want to reply to any message sent in DMs, you can just add a check at the top.

```
if(!message.guild) return;
```